# How to find average using map reduce in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

My document is of format:

```
{
  "PItems": {
    "Workspaces": [
      {
        "Key": "Item1",
        "Size": 228.399,
        "Foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Item2",
        "Size": 111.399,
        "Bar": "baz"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Item2",
        "Size": 636.66,
        "Baz": "foo"
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

I need to find the average size of each items from all the documents in the collection. How do I do that?

Expected output:

Item1: 346.12

Item2: 563.58

I have tried the following:

```
db.Resources.mapReduce(
  function() { 
    this.PItems.Workspaces.forEach(
       function(z) {
          emit(z.Key, z.Size);
       }
    );
  },
  function(item, space) {
    var total = 0;
    for ( var i=0; i<space.length; i++ )
        total += size[i];
    return { avg : total/space.length };
  },
  out: { inline: 1 }
);
```

I am getting a syntax error:  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why mapreduce not aggregation? As aggregation is much faster then the mapreduce

Comment: Edited the example. In my case item can repeat in a document. How can I do it using aggregation?

Comment: Could you post the expected output as well

Comment: Edited with expected output

Comment: Your expected output is not being produced by your sample collection. Could your explain how `Item1: 346.12

Item2: 563.58`?

Comment: The average is over multiple documents. Only one document is shown in the above example. I wanted to point out that the key can repeat in a single document which is why I thought map reduce may be the way to go.

Comment: My be you are looking for something like this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$PItems.Workspaces"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$PItems.Workspaces.Key",
      average: {
        $avg: "$PItems.Workspaces.Size"
      }
    }
  }
])` https://mongoplayground.net/p/isr2COOVTjF

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. Was not aware of "$unwind"!